# Declare an array with pointer in C

Tags: c

Why is this syntax illegal in C?

```
int *a = {1,2,3};
```

Aren't arrays and pointers the same thing? Why would this work and not the above?

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int *b = a;
```

Comment: Obviously they are not the same ;). You can convert an array into a pointer but not the other way round. Also `sizeof(a)` and `sizeof(b)` will give you very different results in your second example.

Comment: "Aren't arrays and pointers the same thing?"; No, they're actually slightly different (a difference which is further muddied by the fact that arrays will oft _decay_ to a pointer to the first element thereof).

Comment: As far as I understand it, arrays are static whereas pointers are dynamic which is why that doesn't work

Comment: Arrays and pointers are quite different, even though arrays are automatically converted to pointers under certain circumstances.  In your case, you're attempting to create an anonymous array, then initialize a pointer variable to point to it (actually, to its first element).  There is a syntax for doing so:  `int *a = (int []) {1, 2, 3};` will work.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Yes, but you have to be very careful with that. `a` ends up pointing to an object with automatic lifetime, so you cannot, for example, return `a` from a function.

Comment: @rici It has the same storage class that an array would have, i.e. it's the same as `int anon[] = {1, 2, 3}, *a = anon;`  But at the file level, the storage would presumably be permanent.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, at file scope it's a static object. But I often see it used in function scope where it turns into a dangling pointer.

Comment: Reopened because the question explicit asks about the initialization syntax, which is a distinct question from whether arrays are pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this syntax illegal in C?

In `int a[] = {1,2,3};`, the `{1,2,3}` is a syntax for providing initial values of the things being initialized. A list of values in braces is a general notation for listing initial values. It is not a notation for representing an array.

The declaration says `a` is an array, but that is just in its `int a[]` part. The `{1,2,3}` does not indicate an array—it just provides a list of values, and it could be used for non-array objects, such as providing values for the members of a structure.

In `int *a = {1,2,3};`, the `int *a` part defines `a` to be a pointer. A pointer just has one value in it—the address of something (or null). So it does not make sense to initialize it with multiple values. To initialize a pointer, you need to provide an address for it to point to.

There is a notation in C for representing an array of given values. It is called a compound literal, and can be used for types in general, not just arrays. Its syntax is “(*type*) { *initial values* }”. So we can create an array with `(int []) {1, 2, 3}`. A pointer could be defined and initialized to point to this array with `int *a = (int []) {1, 2, 3};`. However, this should be done with care. Such an array is temporary (has automatic storage duration that ends when execution of its associated block ends) when defined inside a function, so the pointer will become invalid when the function returns (or before, if it is in an inner block).